# How to create a children container that has all the remain height of the screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

Here I want to have a layout with a full-screen-height **container** and on top of it is some text, and a **container** that has all the remain height of the screen.

My widget tree looks like this :

```
Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  child: ListView(
    children: [
      Container(
        child: Text(),
      ),
      Container(
        ...
      ), // Need to fill the rest space
    ],
  ),
);
```

So how can I do that, I had tried to use **column** and **expanded** but the screen ends up showing nothing.

[The layout I want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAP4T.png)

[My layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8jto.png)

Comment: Does your second `Container()` have a child or is it empty right now?

Comment: It has a column of form field now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a `Column` and `Expanded`, see below. The problem with `ListView` is that it has no size limit, so you can't tell the other widget to occupy all remaining space because there is no such as total space. But you can add a `ListView` inside the `Expanded` widget if you need.

```
return Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        child: Text('aaaa'),
      ),
      Expanded(
          child: Container(
              child: Text('bbbb'),
              color: Colors.red)), // Need to fill the rest space
    ],
  ),
);
```